# How to Set TableViewCell Focus colour in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, focus, tvos

Default focus color of UITableViewCell is white colour. 
How can we change the focus colour of UITableView cell?

Answer (score 3):

You can set this as in the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    cell.focusStyle = UITableViewCellFocusStyleCustom;
    // ...
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    if ([context.previouslyFocusedView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        context.previouslyFocusedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if ([context.nextFocusedView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        context.nextFocusedView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a swift code. Please convert to Objective-C and try it. It maybe help you.

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

if let nextFoc = context.nextFocusedView as? YourCellName{

       nextFoc.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

}

if let prevFocus = context.previouslyFocusedView as? YourCellName{

        prevFocus.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}
```

Look it a screen shot.

[image: initial focus image][image: Second focus image][image: Third focus image]

Comment: Tried same in Objective C... but still the focus colour of cell does not change

Comment: Where did you write this code, on my side  it's working properly. You will write this code into the custom cell class.

Comment: Custom cell background changes...but the default focus style animation of tableviewcell(parallax) goes away.

Comment: Look it this link may be help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373775/swift-how-do-i-create-a-parallax-effect-in-uitableview-with-uiimageview-in-thei

Comment: Thanks for the help... I found one more solution to it. I added a view on custom cell and mapped it to cell background view. So when tableview focus update method is called i just change the background view colour...then the colour changes with default tableviewcell parallax animation

Comment: @GAURAVVIG Thanks, I had the same problem and your last solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the fancy parallax cells you can first set a background view on your custom cell:

```
self.backgroundView = UIView()
```

And in your viewcontroller with the tableview do something like this:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    (context.nextFocusedView as! MyCustomTableviewCell).backgroundView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    if let prev = context.previouslyFocusedView as? MyCustomTableviewCell {
      // Set the color back to whatever it was, in this case I have a black background with black cells
      prev.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom `tableViewCell`, then you can use the delegate method of the `tableViewCell` as below,

```
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    if (self.focused)
    {
        [self showHighlightedCellStyle];//set highlighted bg color
    }
    else
    {
        [self showNormalCellStyle];//reset the bg color
    }
}
```