# How to create Parallax Effect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, parallax

How is this parallax effect done?

[image]

Now let's say we had a paged `UIScrollView` and inside each page/section there was a `UITableView` and that image above with the cool parallax was inside of a `UITableViewCell`, so as you scroll left and right in the paged `UIScrollView`, you would see the parallax effect within the `UITableViewCell`'s. The parallax effect in this case would be **horizontal** like the video above, not vertical when scrolling up and down the `UITableView`. Could anyone please show or point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I feel like you can use answer #31373775 to build that. Just listen to the scroll from the UIScrollView instead of the UITableView, switch height/width and x/y in the methods and see what you get.

Comment: @Nycen I will give it another shot with your answer there - thanks!